# Moodle page images are not loading

Tags: php, url, moodle

My goal is to display images after creating a moodle page. The images are not displaying.
I have looked on moodle forum and still no luck. I have two urls here.

First is: `http://localhost/moodle/draftfile.php/46/mod_page/content/2/img.jpg`. This url I copied it from the image that is supposed to be displayed on the moodle page.  It doesn't work.

Then there is another:`http://localhost/moodle/draftfile.php?file=%2F5%2Fuser%2Fdraft%2F27292186%2Fffffffffff.png&preview=thumb&oid=1599571860`. This url I copied it from one of the private files which I uploaded. It works perfect.

These are two different urls which load different resources. The form of these urls is what made me suspect something is wrong with first url. I am suspecting the first one is wrong because it's giving me  `404 Not Found`. The second one works correctly.
Can you give me some insight on what to do. How can I fix this?

Comment: I think the problem is the wrong address.

/draftfile.php/46/

Comment: In the second URL, you contact the crypt PHP by passing the GET parameters to it

Comment: In the first url, you are trying to bypass what actually exists as a file

Comment: I figured it out. I have to configure nginx to use slash arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those links mention 'draftfile.php' - the only purpose of this script is to display images whilst they are located in a text editor in a form you are editing. Once you submit the form, the code that the developer writes to handle the form submission should copy these files from the draft area into the permanent file area.

Files that are in the draft area are only available to the user who is editing the form and are automatically deleted after a couple of days (because if the form hasn't been saved by that point, then the files are almost certainly redundant).

The rest of the URLs appear to be from two different sites that have been configured differently - the first is using the 'slasharguments' setting enabled (which works on most servers), the second was generated with 'slasharguments' setting disabled (which is a fallback for servers that do not support 'slasharguments', so have a ?file= param instead).

The first URL is odd, as, despite being served via draftfile.php, the rest of the details relate to a permanent file area (component: mod_page, file area: content). The second seems to have details that correctly relate to a draft file area (component: user, file area: draft).

What is not clear is how you are creating this page - is this related to some custom code you have written (in which case, you may need to look at how you are preparing and saving the data - see https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_the_File_API_in_Moodle_forms for more details). If you are creating the page via the user interface, have you copied and pasted some of the content from somewhere else? If so, that might explain why the link is broken (it is referring to a file that existed in the context it was copied from, but not in the context where it was pasted).

Comment: I figured out the slash arguments part. Now I am configuring nginx to use slash arguments. Thank you.